# capsys gets corrupted, probably a step is evaluated twice when using pytest-bdd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bdd, pytest

I would like to assert that something is written to the standard output with **pytest-bdd**. Here is my `stdout.feature` file:

> ```
> Feature: test writing to stdout
>     We are testing stdout capturing
>
> Scenario: Trying to capture stdout
>     Given we have written to stdout
>     Then the result can be captured via capsys
> ```

And here is the correspondig `test_stdout.py`:

> ```
> from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, then
>
> @scenario('stdout.feature', 'Trying to capture stdout')
> def test_stdout_capture(capsys)::
>     pass
>
> @given('we have written to stdout')
> def test_stdout_write(capsys):
>     print('Hello')
>
> @then('the result can be captured via capsys')
> def test_written_to_stdout(capsys):
>     out, err = capsys.readouterr()
>     assert out == 'Hello\n'
> ```

However when running `pytest -v`, I got a strange assertion error:

> ```
> ...
> collected 2 items 
>
> test_stdout.py::test_stdout_capture PASSED
> test_stdout.py::test_written_to_stdout FAILED
> ...
> >       assert out == 'Hello\n'
> E       assert '' == 'Hello\n'
> E         + Hello
>
> test_stdout.py:16: AssertionError
> ```

It seems like `test_stdout_capture` already executes `test_written_to_stdout` where the contents of stdout is lost, as when I change the assertion (ie. `assert out == 'Goodbye'`) I get another assertion error beside this.

What may cause this?